# mysq: Using the same subquery in FROM and WHERE clause without repeating it?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to select data with all the cars that have been the longest in a workshop. So if the max of days is 16 and there are multiple cars with 16 days I need all of them.

---

My models are like this

**Car**: id_car, mat_car, mod_car, color, type

**Period**: id_per, date_ini, date_fin

**Relacion4**: id_car, id_per

---

This method works but is there a way to do it with without repeating the same subquery in FOR and in WHERE clause as well?

```sql
select * from (
    select Car.mat_car, mod_car, color, type, date_ini, date_fin, datediff(date_fin, date_ini) daysInWorkshop from Car
    inner join Relacion4 on Car.mat_car = Relacion4.mat_car
    inner join Period on Relacion4.id_per = Periodo.id_per
) as CarWithDurr
where daysInWorkshop = (
    select max(daysInWorkshop) from (
        select datediff(date_fin, date_ini) daysInWorkshop from Car
        inner join Relacion4 on Car.mat_car = Relacion4.mat_car
        inner join Period on Relacion4.id_per = Period.id_per
    ) as CarWithDurr
);
```

Comment: You could create a view. Or maybe there's a way to optimize that query.

Comment: You don't need to join relacion4 and car to get max days. But you do need to repeat some in the where. The select * from is unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can slim down a bit.

```
    select Car.mat_car, mod_car, color, type, 
          date_ini, date_fin, datediff(date_fin, date_ini) daysInWorkshop 
    from Car
    inner join Relacion4 on Car.mat_car = Relacion4.mat_car
    inner join Period on Relacion4.id_per = Periodo.id_per
    where datediff(date_fin, date_ini) = 
    (
    select max(datediff(date_fin, date_ini)) 
    from Period
    )
    ;
```

If this doesn't work as you wish please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

btw WHERE DO YOU GET Relacion4.mat_car it isn't in your published table!! AND Periodo is misspelled.